# Usage of "marcharse" and "irse"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos

What is the difference between marcharse and irse? Do they both mean ' to go' ?

1. Yo me voy a la escuela.
2. Yo me marcho a la escuela.

Comment: I would add "synonyms" tag to this question, unleast you are asking for their usage in several parts of the spanish world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, I think both phrases means the same.

The assumption is that "marcharse" indicates to go from some place, and "irse" to go to some place.

> Me voy *(de aquí/ from here)* a casa = Me marcho a casa
>
> Me voy *(from my confortable bed and home)* al trabajo = Me marcho al trabajo
>
> Ya te vas *(de aquí?)* = Ya te marchas?

Comment: I just think they are synonyms. I'm trying to think a situation where you cannot use both of them... the only one I can imagine is related with sexual content :O

Comment: For example, it will be strange if you say "Marcho al baño", instead "Voy al baño"... Or "Voy a por un café" I think sounds better than "Marcho a por un café".

Comment: That sounds fine to me. I guess I am used to the way people in north Spain talks, so my friends from Galicia usually talks that way. But you are right, some spanish people can hear it strange :)

Comment: Because galicians are so undecided that doesn't know if they are "marchándose" or "yéndose" < (Just a common spanish joke about galicians) ;) Anyway, talking seriously, thanks for the comment, I think it's important to see all possible nuances! :D

Comment: You are totally right xDDD